# XSL- Boolean value not updating inside when block

Tags: xslt

Hello I am trying to transfer information from xsl to pdf, wherein need to check some value regarding display. For e.g. Display a logo only once to avoid repetitive logo in the pdf. I have added logic using a variable, but it seems there is an issue with the value in the variable, an extract of the code is below with comments:

```
<xsl:template name="show">
    <xsl:variable name="display" select="false()"/>
    <fo:block>
        Fruits
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:for-each select="Fruits/Fruit">
        <xsl:variable name="FruitType" select="type"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($display) and contains($FruitType, 'Ground')">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:variable name="FilePath" select="/imagesDir"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="FullFileName" select="concat($FilePath,'\', $Fruits_Logo_ImageFile)"/>
                    <fo:external-graphic src="url(file:///{$FullFileName})" content-height="scale-to-fit" height="15pt" content-width="15pt"/>
               Fruits
               
            <xsl:variable name="display" select="true()"/><!-- The value is updated to true here -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$display"/>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="$display"/>
            <!-- The value is false here but was updated to true in the when block-->
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </fo:block>
```

I need to update the value of variable 'display' when its printed once but doesnt seem to be updated as it is false again in the block where i print the title. What could be possibly wrong or missing in this. Thanks for any input.

Comment: XSLT variables are immutable. You are not updating the variable, you are shadowing it - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#dt-shadows.

Comment: @michael.hor257k so whats the right way to update the variable, i am not so expereinced with XSLT hence the question.

Comment: There is no way to update the variable. There is another way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do (which is not clear at this point). I suggest you ask a new question regarding your *real* problem - and make sure to include a [mcve] and state the version of XSLT you are using. See also: https://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: The intent here seems to be to treat elements before the first `Fruit/@Type="Ground"` in one way, and elements after that one differently. The easiest way to do that is to first find that element, then process its preceding-siblings in one for-each (or mode), and its following-siblings in a different for-each (or mode).